# Xcode for debugging torch7?

Tags: xcode, deep-learning, torch

I am a newer to deep learning and torch7! I was searching an environment for coding in mac. I am using ZeroBrane in ubuntu, but I was wondering if
there is anyway that I can use Xcode for debugging torch7. Can it work like ZeroBrane?